# Meteor npm install not properly installing packages

Tags: meteor

I'm having a weird issue where, upon starting a clean build of an app which was working previously, and running `meteor npm install` then `meteor`, I get a bunch of errors:

[image]

I suspect that for some reason, meteor npm install isn't running properly. I've reinstalled meteor, run `meteor reset`, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: You could try `npm rebuild` or `rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: @Mikkel thanks for the suggestions, tried both but neither worked.

Comment: did you try `npm install` without `meteor` prefix?

Comment: I had errors like these very often as a follow-up error, where the real source of error occured somewhere in the server/client/startup code but the parser just skipped it and then threw weird errors on the client about missing packages. Maybe there is somewhere a comma or semicolon missing? Do you have a linter? Maybe it can reveal some "unclean" code sections.

Comment: The key clue here is `meteorInstall is not defined`, which indicates that Meteor does not start properly in your app. All the previous errors are related to that one. I have observed that incorrect code might end up with this kind of error. Usually it is not related at all to npm or Atmosphere packages themselves.

Comment: Did you actually added the packages using `meteor npm install --save ...` ?